# cocoa detect text changed

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I just started OS X development with Cocoa, but I got many basic problems.

How can I detect text changed from NSTextField something like onTextChanged() in Java?
Someone said that make delegate, but I can't understand what is delegate, and what it does.

I use cocoa framework with Xcode 5.0.2.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class declaration add the NSTextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
@interface MyView : NSView <NSTextFieldDelegate>
```

Then in code set:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Now your textfield will send notifications to the delegate, and you can implement whichever delegate function you want (see NSText Delegate Method Implementations in the link below)

What you say you need now is to implement:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

   //Do stuff here

}
```

Reference: [NSTextField Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Well,, i get this error
`Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'MyView'; did you mean 'NSView'?`

Comment: just write NSView instead of UIView since you are programming Cocoa not Cocoa Touch

Comment: You should put your textfield's name instead of 'myTextField'.

If you have created it in Interface Builder, then you should create an IBOutlet for your textfield.

If you don't know what these are, you have quite a bit of studying to do: http://trabelous.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/what-are-iboutlet-and-ibaction/

Comment: `NSTextFieldDelegate` does not have a `textDidChange:` method.  Instead one should use `controlTextDidChange:`, an `NSControl` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

In-spite of writing code you can implement the same thing through binding as well. Just connect your `textfield` to the delegate of `fileowners`. Like that below:-

[image]

And then implement this below method. So that no need to define `NSTextFieldDelegate` `protocol` in header file and no need to set `delegate`in implementation file through code :-

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{

}
```